# Listing parent section in search results

Tags: search, template-tags

I'm building a search results template and want to display the parent section of the website for each result returned. so at the bottom of each search result excerpt it'd say "Found in [section] | Reacd More"

Something like: http://www.foxglovecovert.org.uk/search/results/search&keywords=local/

Comment: How are you defining "section"? Category, parent page, template, something super cool that I don't even know exists?

Comment: I'd like "blog", "gallery"(custom post format), "event"(custom post format), "about"(parent page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your custom post types and your blog, you can use [get_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type). For your About parent page, if the pages only go one level deep, you can check `$post->post_parent` to see if it's the about page. Otherwise, you can use [get_post_ancestors()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors) and check that array to see if your About page is in it!

Comment: Thanks.  I think I can write the function I need from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_get_highest_parent( $id ) {
    $cat = get_category( $id );
    $parent = $cat->parent;

    if( $parent == 0 ) 
        return $id;
    else
        my_get_highest_parent( $parent );
}
```

That will get you the highest level parent (the category with parent 0) based on the category-id you feed into it